# Blender python - set location does not use centimeters

Tags: python, units, measurement

I can update a 3d object position with:

```
some_3d_variable.obj.location = (0, 1, 0)
```

This sets this object in meters i.e. 100 centimeters:

[image]

This is not what I expected since I set the scene to use centimeters:

```
scene.unit_settings.length_unit = 'CENTIMETERS'
```

Can I do something, such that when I write

```
some_3d_variable.obj.location = (0, 1, 0)
```

I get

[image]

(Yes I know I can divide the number with 100 in python but I need to do this a million times and it looks bad)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### I think the only way is to multiply by a factor to get the correct python value

```
import bpy
from bpy.utils.units import to_value, to_string

unit_settings = bpy.context.scene.unit_settings
unit_system = unit_settings.system
unit_length = unit_settings.length_unit
unit_scale = bpy.context.scene.unit_settings.scale_length

def get_factor(s): # raise error if wrong input and unit_scale != 0
    return to_value(unit_system, "LENGTH", s, str_ref_unit=unit_length) / unit_scale

fac = get_factor("1")

bpy.context.object.location[0] = 5*fac

#### test
# Assume:
#   unit_length = 'CENTIMETERS'
#   unit_scale = 1.5
#### result of location x
print(bpy.context.object.location[0])
print("0.03333333134651184")
print("display: 5 cm")
```

#### Area and Volume

```
import bpy
from bpy.utils.units import to_value, to_string

unit_settings = bpy.context.scene.unit_settings
unit_system = unit_settings.system
unit_length = unit_settings.length_unit
unit_scale = bpy.context.scene.unit_settings.scale_length

def get_factor(s): # raise error if wrong input and unit_scale != 0
    return to_value(unit_system, "LENGTH", s, str_ref_unit=unit_length) / unit_scale

fac = get_factor("1")
fac2 = fac * fac
fac3 = fac2 * fac

area = 5 * fac2
volume = 5 * fac3

# suppose:
#   unit_length = 'CENTIMETERS'
#   unit_scale = 1.5
print("area=", area) #area= 0.00022222221244444452
print("display: 5 cm^2")
print()
print("volume=", volume) #volume= 1.4814813837037057e-06
print("display: 5 cm^3")
```

Comment: ah that's a bummer. Thanks for the explanation

Comment: AFAIK Blender's unit is really just a display thing, it does not change the actual inputs and scene's units.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can have Blender interpret `bpy.context.object.location = (0, 1, 0)` as $1$ centimeter. By default, even if *Length* is set to *Centimeters* it would still interpret the code in meters (as 100cm), but by setting the *Unit Scale* under *Scene Properties > Units* to $0.01$ you can have it interpret your values directly in centimeters instead of meters.

```
import bpy

bpy.context.scene.unit_settings.scale_length = 0.01
bpy.context.object.location = (0, 1, 0) # will set as 1cm
```

[image]